# autocomplete_fields wont work on ForeignKey from another app

Tags: django, autocomplete, field

I am new to Django I am using `autocomplete_fields`, Here is the Case. I have an app named Contacts where I am getting contact information and there is another app named school where I am Enrolling Contacts as person from my Contact app

#models.py

```
class FacultyRegistration(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="Faculty Role")
    contact = models.ForeignKey('Contacts.Contact', related_name='faculty_Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference = models.ForeignKey('Contacts.Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='faculty_reference', )
```

Here I am registering person and using my Contact app for it

#admin.py

```
@admin.register(FacultyRegistration)
class PersonRegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'role', 'contact', 'reference')
    list_filter = ('role',)
    list_display_links = ('id', 'role', 'contact', 'reference', 'contact',)
    autocomplete_fields = ["role", 'contact', 'reference']
    search_fields = ['role__person_role', 'contact__first_name', 'contact__middle_name', 'contact__last_name', 'reference__first_name', 'reference__middle_name', 'reference__last_name']
```

the issue is when I go to my admin panel I get searchable drop downs as expected

but when I start typing to search my contact it wont fetch contacts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdpZo.png)

and it gives this error in console

**django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup ‘icontains’ for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted.
[22/Jan/2024 12:33:08] “GET /autocomplete/?term=stu&app_label=school_app&model_name=facultyregistration&field_name=contact HTTP/1.1” 500 191958**

however it works fine with my roles, maybe bcz roles are in same application